# Texture Painting Work Disappeared!

Tags: texture-painting

I am new to Blender but have created one elaborate texture painting on a 3D object I imported in with great success. Months later, the object shape needed adjustment and the painting design needed some tweaks, so I imported the new 3D shape and discovered the stencil tool to paint perspective snapshots (from the first project) onto the same perspective view of my new model/project to save time. I was nearly done but was having some crashes when I browsed for additional perspective shots to stencil. Upon reopening the program, my painting had disappeared but the 3D shape and background texture color were still there. I then tried opening autosaved recovery files from earlier in the day and all of them were missing the painting only. Have I hopefully just managed to toggle off some setting/workspace/window that allows me to view the paint or did I some how permanently delete the "paint file?" from the project. I seem to recall hitting shift+tab around this crash and thought that might have hidden my work? I could use some suggestions Please!!! I've attached a shot of my work environment from the previous successful file and the new file missing the paint in case there is some setting changed that I am not noticing).  [image: Successful Painting and workspace- File 1]  [image: Missing Paint and Workspace - File 2]

Comment: All painting work has to be saved into the image file being used as a texture to save the image info except when using the Pack image in file function - you can then pack the image complete with the paint dabs into the file, but then need to unpack to save it to disk as a separate image later.

Comment: Craig,  Not sure how the texture paint file was deleted, but your advice has worked great.  I've saved the image diligently as I go (as well as the overall project) and the packing option worked great to save/send the overall project (with the image) to my team.